# get the value from Intent of android

Tags: android, android-intent

Thanks in advance.
When I print `Log.d("me",getIntent().toString());`

I am getting:

`Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED dat=tel:888 flg=0x13800000 cmp=com.ninetology.freecall.two/.CallFinalActivity }`

I am trying to fetch the value which is associated with "dat" but I am getting NullPointer exception.

```
//the code I am using is
getIntent().getStringExtra("dat"); // no use
//i tried 
getIntent().getExtras("dat").toString(); // NullPointer exception
```

I tried with "tel" as key in above code still no use.

Comment: What is your put command, where you are setting the dat value?

Comment: Thnks thepoosh for comment. But I want that data for my application. How can I achieve that

Comment: Thnks  M Mohsin Naeem for comment, I am not putting any thing manually. that is the data fetched from default dialer.

Comment: @SharanabasuAngadi look at the answer I posted. my comment was a mistake

Comment: @SharanabasuAngadi : Yes, look at the answer thepoosh posted. It is correct - use `getIntent().getData()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it seems you're doing this wrong.

1. The `getExtras()` function returns a bundle that you can extract data from and not a function that returns a specific String.
2. `dat` is NOT a String value as you can see from the data that was printed. it's a `Uri`,

try parsing it as you should and I'm sure you'll be able to get the data.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle b) { //mistyped
    super.onCreate(b);
    Uri data = getIntent().getData();
    // OR USE THIS
    String data = getIntent().getDataString();
    // DO STUFF
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Its not necessary the string from Intent your are getting in log have a object with values..

So its better to just check its not a **null**, like,

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

if(bundle ! = null)
{
  // Now check you bundle object which has a values or not  
}
else
{
  // 1. get data in form of Uri
  Uri data = getIntent().getData();

  // 2. OR get string of Uri
  String dataString = getIntent().getDataString();

  // 3. Or split the data string

  // The logic from this part may be different on your requirement.. I only suggests you to get data from string.. (Actual logic may different on your case)
  String data = getIntent().toString();
  data = data.subString(data.indexOf(":"), data.indexOf("flg")-1);
  Log.e("tel:", data);
}
```

Comment: Damn that is ugly. Is there no way to figure it out where it is stored in extras instead of doing a subString call?

Comment: @PoweRoy - Yes, ugly way, but he try to get the data from intent which has not defined values in it. So this could be option for it. The logic should be change on his requirements.

Comment: also, it would also probably give you some false values, if the "tel:" section is not followed by "flg"...

Comment: Thanks for Ans. Still "Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();" bundle is null. So no other way to do than splitting the string as in else part ?

Comment: Yes, That's why I mentioned, your intent returns null bundle, So split the string from intent, But first check the length and data contains in that string. Else you got Exception on it.

Comment: @user370305 : There is no need to use `getIntent().toString()` and then split it - that is a hack. The `dat=` part of `dat=tel:888` indicates this is the `Uri` part of the `Intent` and it can accessed using either `getData()` or `getDataString()` as thepoosh points out.

Answer (score 1):

try `getIntent().getExtras().get("dat");`

Comment: Thanks for ans. getIntent().getExtras() itself is null, then it will throw nullpointer exception for getIntent().getExtras().get("dat"); ......

Answer (score 0):

When you want to pass the data with the intent just add the below code before starting activity

`intent.putExtra("dat", value);`   //value=the value you want to send

And when you want to fetch the same value in another activity just do:

```
Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
if(bundle!=null){
      String string=bundle.getString("dat");
       }
```

By doing this, you wont get the null pointer exception and will help you.