# How to save the value from intent to variable and pass it to webservice api?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to store the value (email id) which I got from extra (intent) to a variable and save it to my database using webservices. I've already created my api and just want to pass that variable which contains the intent value.

```
//INTENT CODE
 Intent intent = getIntent();
    String text = intent.getStringExtra(Select.EXTRA_TEXT);
    email_id.setText(text);


//Passing params e.g
 params.put("name", name);
 params.put("address", address);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get the value from Intent of android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11339203/get-the-value-from-intent-of-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While receiving data you can make use of this which look perfectly fine.

```
String text = getIntent().getStringExtra(Select.EXTRA_TEXT);
email_id.setText(text);
```

Now you want to pass this email in parameter to API. Make sure you know how to call API. This is one of the way you can pass data.

```
params.put("name", name);
params.put("address", address);
params.put("email", email_id.getText().toString().trim());
```

you can pass email_id data in params.

Answer (score -1):

try this to get value

```
//send
 Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), youtActivity.class);
   i.putStringExtra("name", "abcd");
    i.putStringExtra("address", "****");
 startActivity(i)

//receive
    Intent i = getIntent();
    String name= i.getStringExtra("name");
    String address= i.getStringExtra("address");
```

Comment: Do you want to save on local app or on server?